# How to verify TPS is achieved from Aggregate Summary report in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to verify one of API TPS.

6TPS is Requirement.

I have given 6 user load , 1s pacing and runned for 1hr.
Output snap attached.

From the Output how do i verify that API is achieved 6TPS.

Thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4i8M.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the number of TPS for `Get_id` transaction is 1.9 per second so my expectation is that you either need to remove pacing or increase the number of users or both.

You can reach 6 TPS with 6 users only if response time is 1 second (or less), looking at your results it can be as high as 5.6 seconds so either your server cannot server 6 transactions per second of you just need to add more users.

If you want to check the throughput automatically and fail the test if the expected number of transactions per second is not met you can consider running your JMeter test using [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) as a wrapper, Taurus provides flexible and powerful [Pass/Fail criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/#Pass-Fail-Criteria) which can check multiple metrics and return non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) in case if throughput will be lower than your expectations.

More information: [Failure Criteria](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005910205-Failure-Criteria)